# Unable to use prime function in Hackerrank

Tags: ruby

Here is [a link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ruby-lazy) where I m executing the program. I am calling prime function but it gives the error as below. I m new to ruby , please help.

Code that I am executing.

```
prime_pal_array = -> (num) do
  1.upto(Float::INFINITY).lazy.select{|x| prime?(x) and palindromic?(x)}.first(num)  
end

puts prime_pal_array.(5)
```

I am getting error as below.

```
in `block (2 levels) in
': undefined method `prime?' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method `prime?` in the [Core API](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/). You'll have to either define a new method `prime?` yourself or use the [Standard Library's](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/) implementation by adding `require 'prime'` to the beginning of your script.

This however will not fix your code as there is also no such `'palindromic?'` method within the Core library nor Standard library. So either make one up or download and install a relevant gem at [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/).

The above two steps will help you get started in fixing your code.

Comment: But even the `Prime` library doesn't define a global `prime?` function.

Comment: @Stefan Not sure what you mean? e.g. `5.prime? #=> true` if you load the prime.rb file which includes [`prime?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Integer.html#method-i-prime-3F)

Comment: I mean that there's no `prime?(5)` as used in the OP's code.

Comment: @Stefan I had hoped the OP would suss that out himself and use `prime?` accordingly.